# Retrieving all records with 'connection status' using SQLite and Java

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite, android-studio

I'm working on an Android application that utilizes a SQLite database to store and manage music data. I've encountered an issue with a method in my `DatabaseHelper` class that aims to retrieve all bands associated with a specific song, along with their connection status.  So all band names (`band_name`) from the `bands` table should be returned and when the `band_id` is contained in the `songs_bands` table the boolean `isConnected` should be set to 1, otherwise the `isConnected` will be 0.

The method receives an `int` value for the `songId` parameter and is expected to return a `List` of `BandInfo` objects. Each `BandInfo` object should contain the band's ID, name, and a boolean value indicating whether the band is connected to the specified song (`isConnected`).

Here is the method from `DatabaseHelper`:

```
    public List<BandInfo> getAllBandsWithConnectionStatus(int songId) {
        List<BandInfo> bandList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // Query to retrieve all bands with connection status for a specific song
        String[] columns = {"bands._id", "bands.band_name", "CASE WHEN songs_bands.band_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS is_connected"};
        String selection = "songs_bands.song_id = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(songId)};

        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                "bands LEFT JOIN songs_bands ON bands._id = songs_bands.band_id",
                columns,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
            int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("band_name");
            int isConnectedColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("is_connected");

            do {
                int bandId = cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex);
                String bandName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
                int isConnected = cursor.getInt(isConnectedColumnIndex);

                BandInfo bandInfo = new BandInfo(bandId, bandName, isConnected == 1);
                bandList.add(bandInfo);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        // Print the list of BandInfo objects before returning
        for (BandInfo bandInfo : bandList) {
            Log.d("SplashActivityZZ", "(DatabaseHelper) BandInfo in list: " + bandInfo.toString());
        }
        return bandList;
    }
```

The problem arises when I execute this method. Instead of returning a complete List of `BandInfo` objects, the `bandList` only contains the connected bands. The non-connected bands are not included in the list.

I've tried modifying the query and checking for any potential errors in the code, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue. I'm hoping to get some insights on how to correctly retrieve all bands, including those not connected to the specified song, and set their `isConnected` boolean accordingly.

Here are the two tables used within this query - first the `bands`:

```
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_BANDS_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + DatabaseContract.Bands.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    DatabaseContract.Bands._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    DatabaseContract.Bands.COLUMN_BAND_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    DatabaseContract.Bands.COLUMN_BAND_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT)";
```

and the `user_bands`:

```
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_USER_BANDS_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + DatabaseContract.UserBands.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    DatabaseContract.UserBands._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    DatabaseContract.UserBands.COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER, " +
                    DatabaseContract.UserBands.COLUMN_BAND_ID + " INTEGER, " +
                    "FOREIGN KEY (" + DatabaseContract.UserBands.COLUMN_USER_ID + ") REFERENCES " +
                    DatabaseContract.Users.TABLE_NAME + "(" + DatabaseContract.Users._ID + "), " +
                    "FOREIGN KEY (" + DatabaseContract.UserBands.COLUMN_BAND_ID + ") REFERENCES " +
                    DatabaseContract.Bands.TABLE_NAME + "(" + DatabaseContract.Bands._ID + "))";
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work I changed the query, keeping the `LEFT JOIN` but removing the `CASE` as that seemed to be causing the problems.  I am now evaluating the join in the `do while` loop to determine whether there is a connection between the two tables and if there is I am setting the `isConnected` flag to 'true' and if there is not setting to 'false'.  From here I add it into the `bandList` class object.

Here is the adjusted query which now returns everything from the `bands` table and sets the flag `isConnected` when the `band_id` also exists within the `songs_bands` table for the `song_id` being investigated:

```
public List<BandInfo> getAllBandsWithConnectionStatus(int songId) {
    removeDuplicateSongBandPairs();
    List<BandInfo> bandList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


    // Query to retrieve all bands with connection status for a specific song
    String[] columns = {"bands._id", "bands.band_name", "songs_bands.band_id AS isConnected"};
    String selection = null;  // No need for a WHERE clause
    String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(songId)};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            "bands LEFT JOIN songs_bands ON bands._id = songs_bands.band_id AND songs_bands.song_id = ?",
            columns,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
        int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("band_name");
        int isConnectedColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("isConnected");

        do {
            int bandId = cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex);
            String bandName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
            int isConnected = 0;
            Log.d("SplashActivityZZ", "(DatabaseHelper) line #564 - cursor.getString(isConnectedColumnIndex)" + cursor.getString(isConnectedColumnIndex));
            if (!cursor.isNull(isConnectedColumnIndex)) {
                if (isConnectedColumnIndex > 0) {
                    isConnected = 1;
                }
                else {
                    isConnected = 0;
                }
                Log.d("SplashActivityZZ", "(DatabaseHelper) line #567 - cursor.getInt(isConnectedColumnIndex): " + cursor.getInt(isConnectedColumnIndex));
            }
            BandInfo bandInfo = new BandInfo(bandId, bandName, isConnected == 1);
            bandList.add(bandInfo);

            // Log the band information
            Log.d("SplashActivityZZ", "(DatabaseHelper) line #574 - BandInfo in list: " + bandInfo.toString());
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return bandList;
}
```